# How to convert url query string into Xml document using c#

Tags: c#, xml, testing, web

We have a very complex architecture in place where we are standing up three Asp.Net Web API services which are communicating with each other.But now the conundrum is how to test their performance and for the same we are using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version. Visual Studio is a big flop when it comes to capturing WebTest recording and creating a .webtest file, since it captures only those URLs which are generated  when first service talks to the second service but is never ever able to capture all the URLs that are generated when second service talks to the third. And Fiddler is doing the same thing but in a little different way i.e. it captures http requests and responses (which as you guys know is a round trip) but not able to chase down http requests and responses generated for an individual services but that's what we need to know.

Now what we have found, is that IIS logs (since services are deployed in IIS 7) capture all the http URLs along with their requests and responses. And we have devised a mechanism by means of which we strip the log file of all the unnecessary comments/columns(which we don't need for our testing analysis) and then export the resulting output custom file into Sql Server. Hence we have all the URLs in place (in one of the Sql Server table columns) now which we need to generate a WebTest in Visual Studio but what we don't have, is how to convert this list of URLs in an XML document and create a .webtest file (since .webtest file is an XML file) for Load Testing in Visual Studio.

Any help on this account would be highly appreciated.

Comment: TL;DR;... Please remove whining and provide clear question.

Comment: I'm sorry that you can't understand such a clear question.

Comment: All I'm asking for is how to convert list of url qury strings to an xml document and hence create a .webtest file for visual studio.

Comment: And custom .webtest file created by us should exactly match the .webtest file created by visual studio in terms of its xml format with all the elements n attributes matching in  order for visual studio to understand and do a load test